# how to add input required attribute? And how to let a button do two things during one onclick event?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
export default function Modal({onClose}){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [Name, setName] =useState("");
    const [Email, setEmail] =useState("");

    return (
        <div className="background">
            <div className="modalContainer">

                <div className="title">
                    <h1>Continued As Guest</h1>
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <div className="body">
                    <form className="Guest" >
                        <input type="text" name = "GuestName" placeholder="Name"  value={Name}
                               onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value);}}
                        />

                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <input type="Email" placeholder="Email" value={Email}
                               onChange={(event) => {setEmail(event.target.value);}}/>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <div className= "footer">
                            <button id = "cancel"
                                    onClick={()=>onClose(false)}>Cancel</button>
                                <button    formAction=" https://stackoverflow.com/"
                                    type = "button"
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        dispatch(addGuest({
                                            Name:Name, Email:Email}));
                                    }}
                                >Continue</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I try to create a form in the modal box. This form include two inputs "GuestName" and "Email", and two buttons "Cancel" and "Continue".
I want to add "required" attribute to my "GuestName" input. I also want my continue button to dispatch "addGuest" action and go to a new webpage during the onClick event.

Comment: Do you have some routes? If so can you past them please?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by routes?

Comment: It's best not to write forms yourself but use a form package such as [react-hook-forms](https://react-hook-form.com/)

Comment: On a side-note using <br /> to layout components is not considered a good practice. I would try [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) for semantic layouting.